# Calculating chance of event

Tags: probability

I have edited to better reflect what my question is.

I would like to better understand chance and how to calculate probability. I am presented with three options, A, B, and C, and a prize is arbitrarily assigned to one of them. If I guess the correct option, I get a prize. I have a 33% chance of getting a prize if I guess.

I understand how this works and why this is. I would like to transfer this logic to a different situation. Let's assume I am interested in making a heat map of a persons fixations on a webpage for market research. Again, let's assume there are three options, or, in this case, places somebody can look on the screen: an image that takes up 10% of the screen, another image that takes up 10% of the screen, or anywhere else (the other 80% of the screen). I am interested in knowing if a potential client is looking at one of the images more than anywhere else on the screen (so that I can use it in an ad, for example). I could tell if a client was looking at one area of the screen more by looking at my hypothetical heatmap, but is there a way to calculate if they are doing it above chance if I didn't have a heat map? Is this possible?

If the screen were divided into three equal parts, then I feel like this would be simple (like the example above); however, I can't get my head around how this would work when some areas ('options') are smaller. We can assume that the screen is 100px by 100px (just to simplify the example).

I'm sure that this is a simple question, but I am having trouble wrapping my head around it.

Comment: A large number of factors have a play here.  What are the locations and shapes of the areas? What are the distributions of the ball you are tossing into the box?  If your ball has a cross section of $10$cm$^2$, and the box is $100$cm$^2$, part A and B are 10%, but square shaped, it would be physically impossible for the ball to go into the area if the zones are divided by partitions and going into an area means that the ball went all the way to the bottom of the partition.

Comment: If, on the other hand, this is a thought experiment and you are able to throw the ball with a uniform random distribution and the ball, by definition of the thought experiment, is equally capable of reaching any area inside the box, then the areas would represent expected probabilities of the distribution that you could then test your actual distribution against.

Comment: "How chance is affected by the size of the different parts" is a physical question but not a statistical one.  The other questions, including "what is chance" and "how do I calculate this" do sound statistical, but they are too vague to be answerable.  Could you elaborate on them or clarify them?

Comment: I've edited the question to make it less vague, but I am still rather unhappy with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, you would not be able to tell whether a user looks at a certain picture above chance without any additional information, e.g., without such a heatmap.

However, if you have such a heatmap, you can calculate whether they are focusing on a position on the screen above chance (given an assumption on how users look at screens 'at random'). You would calculate from the heatmap how much time the user has spent looking at pixels belonging to the picture (the ratio of the total time) and compare it to the assumed probability that the user would have looked at those pixels at random.

If you assume completely random behaviour, i.e., every pixel is equally likely to be looked at by the user, the chance that the user looks at a picture at random is equal to the percentage of the total pixels covered by the picture. If each picture takes 1/3 of the screen, the chance is 1/3 for each picture. If one picture takes 1/2 of the screen, and the other two 1/4 each, the probabilities are 1/2, 1/4, and 1/4, respectively.

If you assume a different random behaviour, e.g., the user is more likely to look at the center of the screen following a bivariate normal distribution, then the probability for a pixel to be seen now depends on its location on the screen. You could estimate the probability that the user randomly looks at pixels belonging to a picture numerically by generating these probabilities per pixel (in something like MATLAB or R) and summing over all pixels belonging to that picture. Alternatively, you could do it analytically by integrating over the area in your assumed probability distribution. Option 1 is probably easier.

In this way you would get the assumed probability that a user looks at a picture at random. You could then compare it to the observed behaviour given your heatmap.